# Flutter provider to pass a singe object out of list to the child view

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a page where it shows **ListView** that contains list of **schools**. So I load all the schools (in **initState()** method) when the user clicks on **My Schools**.

Now I want to pass the **School** object when user **clicks** on a **school's** in the **ListView** and show the **edit** **school** page.

I want to use the **provider patter** for this so I can **pass** a **single school object** to the **edit page** and once user done with **edit** and **press back**, it automatically **reflects** the updated **school** in the **ListView**.

I am really confused with how to pass a single object from a list to the edit page. Following is my code where I have model, provider and state classes. As I am not getting how to access the school object in the edit page I have not created it yet.

I **do not want to use** the **constructor** to pass the school object to edit.

```
// School model class
class SchoolModel {
  String name;
  double points; 
}

// school provider
class SchoolProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   School _school;
   School get school => _school;

   set School(School value) {
       _school = value;
        notifyListeners();
   }
}

// School list page
class ListSchool extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _ListSchoolState createState() => _ListSchoolState();
}

// List page state
class _ListSchoolState extends State<ListSchool> {
    List<School> _schools;
    @override
    void initState() {
       _schools = FirebaseCall(); // loading schools
    }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
   body: MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (context) => SchoolProvider(),
              ),
            ],
             child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _schools.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                   return ListTile(
                       title: Text(_schools[index].name);
                       onTap() {
                          // Open Edit page and pass the clicked school object to edit page
                       }
                   );
                }
             )
         )
);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your change notifier, to be the list that you want to update.

```
class SchoolsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   List<School> _schools;
   School get schools => _schools;

   SchoolProvider(this._schools = const []);

   void addSchool(School newSchool) { 
     _schools.add(newSchool); 
     notifyListeners();
   }

   void removeShool(String schoolName) {
     _schools.removeWhere((s) => s.name == schoolName);
     notifyListeners();
   }

   void updateSchool(String shoolName, double points) {
     _schools.removeWhere((s) => s.name == schoolName);
     addSchool(School(schoolName, points));
   }
}
```

When you tap on the ListTile you just push the new page, and pass in the desired school.

```
Consumer<SchoolsProvider>(
    builder: (_, schools, __) => ListView.builder(
     itemCount: schools.length,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(schools[index].name),
        onTap() {
           Navigator.push(context, MaterialRoutePage(
             context,
             builder: (_) => YourNewPage(school: schools[index]),
           ));      
        },
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

From the new page, you can just access the methods declared in the Provider, this will update the listeners

```
class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final School school;
 
  NewPage({this.school});

  ...
  
  //Here you can perform any action on the schools Provider
  // It will notify it's listeners (Consumer) so it gets updated
  schools[index].add
  schools[index].remove
  schools[index].update  

  ...
```

Comment: When the onTap() method runs, I will redirect the use to the edit page of that particular school. So, how can I access the school object in the Edit page of the school. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I edited, the previous answer, take a look now, and let me know

Comment: Actually I do not want use the constructor to pass the objects. Sorry, I would have put this before in the question itself...

Comment: Sam, why don't you want to pass the school object? This is common practice. 

But if you don't want to pass the School object, you can pass the index of the school. or the name. And place another Consumer in the new page, and then access the add/delete/update functions.

Comment: Thanks @Migalv for following. I can pass the school object to the edit page via a constructor but when I change anything in the Edit page, how will it reflect in the ListView page?

Comment: What you do is the following. Then you edit that school object, for ex: `school.points=10;`, then you add, remove or update your schoolList (which is a ChangeNotifier) like so `schoolList.update(school.name, school.points)`, this will notify the listeners (The ListView is a listener because it has the Consumer widget as a parent, and it will update its state with the new list when the list changes) this is because the methods (add/remove/update) we have created for the SchoolsProvider, they call notifyListeners().

Comment: Thanks Migalv for your time and help.